# shell script to recognise jira key

Tags: regex, shell, sed

Below lines in my jenkins job configuration Execute shell retrieves jira key

```
JIRA_KEY=$(curl --request GET "http://jenkins-server/job/myProject/job/mySubProject/job/myComponent/${BUILD_NUMBER}/api/xml?xpath=/*/changeSet/item/comment" | sed -e "s/<comment>\(.*\)<\/comment>/\1/")

JIRA_KEY=$(echo $JIRA_KEY | cut -c10-17)
```

But in case if  text doesn't start with jira key then as per the current logic it will assign any text in the range of 10-17.  I need to store empty string "" in the variable JIRA_KEY when jira key is not present in the `<comment>`, how can we do that?

Here is the xml

```
<freeStyleBuild _class="hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild">
    <changeSet _class="hudson.plugins.git.GitChangeSetList">
        <item _class="hudson.plugins.git.GitChangeSet">
            <comment>
                JRA-1011 This is commit 
                message.
            </comment>
        </item>
    </changeSet>
</freeStyleBuild>
```

Comment: Not clear, could you please let us know what is the expected output, I am seeing you are trying to get characters from 10 to 17,please add more information to post in code tags.

Comment: As mentioned in the post "I need to store empty string "" in the variable JIRA_KEY when jira key is not present in the `<comment>`"

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in comment section it is not clear which output you need, so based on some assumptions, could you please try following and let me know on same.
I- If you need all the strings between  to  then you could run following.

```
awk '/<\/comment>/{a="";next}/<comment>/{a=1;next}a'  Input_file
```

II- If you need to find only JRA string between  to  then you could do following.

```
awk '/<\/comment>/{a="";next}/<comment>/{a=1;next} a && /JRA/{match($0,/[a-zA-Z]+[^ ]*/);print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)}'  Input_file
```

Comment: ok, so could you please let me know which output your are expecting?

Comment: I need to store empty string "" in the variable JIRA_KEY when jira key is not present in the <comment>